# Concise way of writing CSS selector under certain id

Tags: html, css

I think this question was asked before, but I don't know with what term to do the search. Say I have the following code:

```
<div id="my-div">
    <input type="text" class="my-text-input">
    <input type="password" class="my-pwd-input">
    <textarea class="my-textarea"></textarea>
</div>
```

In order to assign certain styles to all 3 elements inside `my-div`, I would write CSS like so:

```
<style>
#my-div .my-text-input, #my-div .my-pwd-input, #my-div .my-textarea {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
</style>
```

Apparently the `#my-div` part is repeated serval times, in some cases, there might be 10 or more of those.

**Question: What's the concise way of writing these CSS selectors?**

Edit:
I need to add a `#my-div` before every element inside because I need something like a namespace, for I'm developing a Chrome extension, and I don't want my floating content page's styles to be messed up with the original page's.

By "all 3 elements inside `my-div`", I mean specifically selected classes, not "all", sorry for the ambiguousness.

@Mumpo's SASS way is what I'm expecting, but is there a "raw" CSS way of doing the same?

Comment: Does "all 3 elements" equal  "all child elements" or do you want to address only some of the child elements?

Comment: id should be unique. if you're using in other 10 elems. change it to class , i'll be fine.

Comment: @Abbr I don't think he's talking about 10 or more elements with the same ID, just 10 or more CSS selectors using the same ID

Comment: on your edited post. why not create a certain e.g. `b-red` with `border:1px solid red;` declared in css, and put the `b-red` on each elem that you want to have this style?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to apply the style to all children elements, you could use:

```
<style>
#my-div * {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
</style>
```

Or assign all children a new class and style that class.

Another option would be to use SASS, which allow you to do nested selectors:

```
#my-div {
    .class1 {}
    .class2 {}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To assign css styles to `all` elements inside you can use:

```
#my-div *{ }
```

If you want assign styles to `all where #my-div is parent of element` use:

```
#my-div > *{}
```

Useful link to selectors description [css selectors](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)

Comment: Good job providing an answer that's true CSS, without the use of a pre-processor that'll spit out the same repetitive CSS anyway.
Maybe also add a multi-class solution like `<tag class="my-input border-red">` / `#my-div .border-red {border: 1px solid red;}`

Answer (score 0):

You should have styles for your inputs regardless of their parent `div`.

```
input, textarea{
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

If you need different styles for certain inputs:

```
<input type="text" class="big-input">

input.big-input{
    height: 40px;
}
```

If you want to apply a state to all the inputs inside a `form` or in your case the `div`:

```
<form class="faded">
    <input type="text" class="big-input">
    <input type="text" class="big-input">
</form>

.faded input{
    opacity: .5;
}
```